# Drupal 9 specific views not displaying for anonymous user after upgradation

Tags: drupal-views, drupal-9

I have a website in Drupal which I upgraded from 8.9.2 to 9.5.9. The site is absolutely working fine except one thing. I have a front page template where multiple views are rendering using twig tweak function. All other view displays are showing on the page except a specific view. That view has 7 displays and none of them are showing on that page. Surprisingly, when I log in as admin and reload the home page, all views are showing but after logout, that view displays are not working on the page--front.html.twig. Even after clearing cache it doesn't work. This issue was not there before upgradation.

These are the steps I tried but nothing changed:

1. Enable the checkbox - Disable views data caching in Advanced Views settings (Views > Settings).
2. Changed the access permission in that view block settings
3. Made a duplicate of that view with different name and chnaged the view name in drupal_view function in page--front template.

Please help me out of this. Thanks in advance.